# Manually indenting lines with tabs

Tags: indentation, formatting, tab-characters, multiple-lines

Lines can be indented with tab characters. And it is quite obvious the there are better ways to do that than manually adding a tab character to the beginning of each line.

But how to discover these ways is less obvious. Looking for help topics about "`indent`" and "`tab`" finds a lot of information about source code formatting with automatic indentation, and about tab pages and the tabstop character.

How to find help about manually indenting lines with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Manually indenting lines with tabs is called shifting in the documentation of vim, the relevant help is found with

```
:h shift-left-right
```